# determine which checkbox is checked by jquery - C# asp,net JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckbLstPartner" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="cssRdlstMoheSacm">
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

In the above CheckBoxList, I'm trying to get the (selected value) by JQuery to hold it and store it in 
 in the DB. Please check the below JQuery:

```
$('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').foreach(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          ***// ??***
        }
        else {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just this

```
$('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').find('option:checked').val();
```

or

```
$('[id$=ckbLstPartner]').find('option:checked').val();
```

Comment: If I want to Unckeck the other option ? What I'v to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Get checked value

```
$('#<%=ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>').find('option:checked').val();
```

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)